# Where to place Rails seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted to know where the best place is to put seed data and more specifically seed files.

Eg. I have a bunch of CSV files > countries.csv, states.csv, categories.csv

At the moment, I'm storing it in my application root but it looks kind of messy. I've been trying to find out where people put their seed data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dedicated place is `db/seeds`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't actually have a db/seeds directory in my Rails 3.2 app. Is that what you meant? My seeds.rb file is referencing the CSV files from the application root atm.

Comment: it's what I mean, this folder was automatically generated before seeds became more controversial. Still, it's the best place for them

Comment: @WasabiDeveloper, just create one. It's just another rails convention, and a fairly logical one at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the seed files under the db/seeds directory.